# Serial.begin(9600); in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to know what Serial.begin(9600); does and if it is necessary to write it in the code.

Comment: Have you done any research yourself? Like googling?

Answer (score 2):

It enables the UART port and sets it to 9600 baud.  Without it you can't use `Serial.print` etc.

Comment: Will the bot work without this?

Comment: Does "the bot" use Serial.print, Serial.read, or Serial.anythingelseatall?

Comment: I'm making an obstacle avoiding bot. I'm not debugging it or using the serial monitor. So, can I exclude it from the code?

Comment: The probably. If you're not using Serial.print, Serial.println or Serial.write then it should be doing nothing.